# SQL Sum of Max 5

Tags: sql, sum, max

I am trying to filter something out from a table. The result shall include [time], [para1], [para2] .....[win rate], [sum of top 5 PL]..... and others. However, I do not know how to code the [sum of top 5 PL]. I would be very pleased if somebody here can help. Thanks In advance

```
SELECT
    ([Time]/500)*500 as [Time]
        ,[Para1]
      ,[Para2]
       ,SUM([PL]) as [Total Profit]
      ,AVG([PL]) as [AVERAGE]
      ,COUNT(*) as [Record Count]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN [PL]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [WinCount]
      ,CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN [PL]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as float) / CAST( COUNT(*)  AS float) as [WINRATE]
      ,MIN([PL]) as [MaxDrawdown]
      ,MAX([PL]) as [MaxProfit]
      ,***************I dunno what to write here*********** [sum of top 5 PL]
      ,AVG(ABS(PL)) as [Average Change]


  FROM [BackTest].[dbo].[HSI_SMA_VB]
  GROUP BY 
        [Para1]
      ,[Para2]
      ,([Time]/500)*500
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30

ORDER BY [Average] DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following to sum up the top 5 PL.

```
SELECT SUM(top_count)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(5) PL as top_count
    FROM test order by top_count desc
) as t;
```